# Excel: function calling seperate cells applied to whole column

Tags: excel, rows

I have 5 variable numbers, lets just say they are 1,2,3,4,5.
Each cell in column A will have one of those numbers. The corresponding cells in columns B and C need to have values based on whatever number is in A.

**For example**

```
 if A1=1,3 or 5 then B1=1 and C1=0.

 if A1=2 or 4 then B1=0 and C1=1
```

**first question is**: Can you write one function for both B and C fetching the A value, or do you need seperate ones for both B and C.

**2nd question:** If B1 and C1 both look at A1, with each row looking at each other (i.e. B12 and C12 would be looking at A12) can I use one function for all of them, or again would I need a seperate one for each row and column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I think that you need to separed the function for B and C because the result of the value in A, each cell going to change. You need to write the same function in B as in C, unless you write a funtion in B that look at the value in A and the in C copy the value in B.

Q2: The same idea as the first question. Each cell needs each function.

Greetings.